# Why cocoa binding won't work with typedef of the framework class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, typedef, cocoa-bindings

Why there is an error, when trying to bind NSColorWell value to some property...

```
valueForUndefinedKey: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key color.
```

If *color* property is defined as:

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) MyColor *color;
```

and *MyColor* is defined as:

```
typedef NSColor MyColor;
```

But everything works OK when *color* property is defined as a NSColor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have found a bug, as `typedef`'s should be transparent and not change behaviour.

Testing shows that with:

```
typedef AnyOldClass SomeOldClass;
```

and properties in different classes:

```
@property AnyOldClass *anyclass; // from class A

@property SomeOldClass *someclass; // from class B
```

then trying to bind the to with `bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:` fails. It does appear to work (i.e. non-exhaustive testing) if the typedef is for a value type (e.g. `double`).

Furthermore it *can* work if it is changed to:

```
typedef AnyOldClass *SomeOldClass;
```

and

```
@property SomeOldClass someclass; // from class B
```

that is the typedef is for the pointer type itself. However not the emphasis on *can*, it doesn't not seem to be consistent between compiles - if it works for a binary it always works for that binary, but a recompilation may break it.

I haven't examined the metadata (at least yet...)

Weird and intriguing. Report it to Apple unless someone jumps in with an explanation soon.

Testing done on Xcode 5.0.2/Clang 4.2